# Python: Is there a more scalable way of looking up all strings in a string?

Tags: python, string, scalability, lookup, string-matching

I have a fairly simple task at hand: given a (lowercased) `big` string and an array of (lowercased) `small` strings, I need to produce 1 if all `small` strings are in the `big` string and 0 otherwise. So a pythonic way of doing this would simply be:

```
>>> big = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> smallTrue = ["quick","dog","fox"]
>>> smallFalse = ["quick","fox","wolf"]
>>> int(all([s in big for s in smallTrue]))
1
>>> int(all([s in big for s in smallFalse]))
0
```

The question is whether there is a different way of getting 0s and 1s that would scale better to a larger number of `big`s that are significantly longer (think of an abstract of a "typical" scientific paper) plus a large set of `small` arrays that are longer?

Scaling means processing time since my machine has a lot of RAM. So if I need to preprocess the data in some way that would require more RAM that would be fine.

The reason for asking is because I ran into some scalability issues doing similar string manipulation tasks.

Comment: Maybe faster without list comprehension since you can short-circuit on the first False result...

Comment: You could break up `big` into a `set()` of words, which (depending on the size of big) makes searching for words faster. However that would probably only make sense if you need to search one given `big` string several times with different `small` strings, and you're searching for words only, not (partial) sentences etc. So - is that your use case ?

Comment: @nos Actually, i do need to search the same `big` with multiple `small` arrays. So are you suggesting splitting the big string into a set of unique words, each small into a set and doing set operations?

Comment: I'm suggesting `big_set = set(big.split())`  and then you could do multiple `any(s in big_set for s in whatever)` Though you might need a different way to split strings than just split() if the input contains punctuation (i.e. you likely want the string "hello. There!" to be the 2 words "hello" "There" and not "hello." "there!".

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a a try. I think splitting by WS is good enough at first, I'll see if I need to use more fancy splitting later.

Comment: Creating a set by splitting ``big`` on whitespace is a good idea, but you'll run into problems if any of your ``small`` strings are more than one word. Just something to keep in mind. If you do have multiple word small strings, you could create a set of ngrams, where n is the longest word count of your small strings

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the square brackets and you'll have a generator instead of a `list` comprehension. It will be evaluated lazily instead of eagerly, avoiding memory issues.

```
all(s in big for s in smallTrue)
```

Also, you probably don't need the `int()` call, as `bool` is a subclass of `int`, with `True` and `False` representing `1` and `0` respectively. You can even do math with them.

Comment: This would definitely make my code more compact. However, I looped `10,000,000` times over my version (`int(all([...`) and yours (`all(...`) and timed both with `time.time()`. Got almost identical numbers

Answer (score 0):

Doing a string lookup in a string will always be slow. If you split big, then run all() on the generator, you should have improved performance

```
big_set = set(big.split(' ')) # you get O(1) lookup on a set
return all(s in big for s in smallTrue)
```